# PHP multiple file upload check empty file

Tags: php, html

Let's say I have a form like this:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File 1 : <input type="file" name="file[]" />
File 2 : <input type="file" name="file[]" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

I want to make sure that each file had upload file. 
Here is my condition and the code that I write: 
File 1 empty:

```
if(empty($_FILES['file']['name'][0]))
{
    echo 'file 1 empty';
}
```

File 2 empty:

```
if(empty($_FILES['file']['name'][1]))
{
    echo 'file 2 empty';
}
```

File 1 and File 2 empty:

```
if(empty($_FILES['file']['name'][0]) && ($_FILES['file']['name'][1]))
{
     echo 'file 1 and file 2 empty';
}
```

Is it possible to write the above condition in for loop? Or just seperately write the code is enough?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with a for or while loop, but if you are always dealing with only 2 files and you also need to know if both files are empty, what you have is pretty efficient. If you are dealing with a more complex situations with multiple files, then rewriting it as a loop is probably better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use foreach

```
$i=1
foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $file){
if(empty($file))
{
    echo "file $i empty";
    $i++
}
}
```